# Finding protein motifs and its position in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am a newbie in Python learning. I want to identify a motif sequence in a large protein        data set.
Using  the one-line code mentioned below, I was able to identify proteins that I am interested in. However, I also want the start and end position of the motif in these proteins. It will be helpful if someone can suggest what additional arguments I have to use along with the below-mentioned code.
thank you in advance.

```py
import re
df.loc[df ['Protein_sequence'].str.contains ("WA[T]R",regex=True)]

Protein_name    Protein_sequence
242 >PST130_487694  MLRFFRLAALVLLMTSWEVAGDTYDPKTKTTYFGCHKNVDAVCSEP...
358 >Pucstr1_10722  MLRFFRSIALVWLMASWEVSTAGKYPNNPDPVNGAKYFGCHKNVDA...
475 >Pucstr1_2774   MLRFLILTALVLLVASWQVTDTLSQDPGDILFWCHKNVDAVCSETI...
```

Comment: Wlcm to stackoverflow. Please read the blog of [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One option using `re.search`:

```
import re

pat = re.compile('WAT?R')

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame([m.span(0) if (m:=pat.search(x)) else (pd.NA,)*2
                            for x in df['Protein_sequence']],
                            index=df.index, columns=['start', 'end'])
             ).dropna(subset=['start', 'end'], how='all')
```

Output (on a modified input):

```
       Protein_name                                   Protein_sequence start end
242  >PST130_487694  MLRFFRLAALVLLMTSWARAGDTYDPKTKTTYFGCHKNVDAVCSEP...    16  19
358  >Pucstr1_10722  MLRFFRSIALVWATRSWEVSTAGKYPNNPDPVNGAKYFGCHKNVDA...    11  15
```

Comment: Thank you so much mozway.. that really solved my problem. one more request if I have to list out the matched pattern as well also along the positions?   As WATR is one of the motifs that are present in these proteins. WA[A-Z]R is the real pattern I am looking for. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You can use `m.group(0)` to get the match, thus `[(*m.span(0), m.group(0)) if (m:=pat.search(x)) else (pd.NA,)*3 for x in df['Protein_sequence']]` and add one more name for the columns

Comment: Thank you so much mozway for your help. it means a lot.